# Помогите с задачей на js

Tags: javascript

Задача в том, чтобы написать  функцию, входным параметром которой является строка. 
Функция должна осуществлять действие, противоположное процедуре сжатия: если в исходной строке встречается подпоследовательность вида x(k), где x – символ, а k – строка, являющаяся записью числа i, то ее необходимо заменить на подпоследовательность, состоящую из   i  вхождений символа x. Также решить без использования строковых функций

Например: строка 1,2(3),3(2) должна принять вид 1,2,2,2,3,3

Прилагаю то, что готово на данный момент (работает только с единичными числами, и не удаляет количество вхождений символа x, то есть при строке 1,2(3),3(2) выведет 1,2223,332)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить и насколько правильные наработки на данный момент?

```js
let str = prompt("Введите строку");
let result = "";

function k(str) {
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == "(") {
      let n = str[i + 1];
      for (let j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
        result += str[i - 1];
      }
      continue;
    }
    if (str[i] == ")")
      continue;
    result += str[i];
  }
  return result;
}

alert(k(str));
```

Comment: решайте задачу  в несколько этапов. сначала разбейте строку на части по запятым. Потом их обрабатывайте отдельно. Проверьте есть в кусочке скобка, нет дак выводите, а если есть то формируйте нужную строку. Реализация всего и сразу только усложняет алгоритм.

Comment: @teran поняла, спасибо, попробую

Comment: @teran, не согласен, что надо делить задачу на части. Конечно, можно считывание чисел вынести, но смысла особого нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy если не получается решить влоб, то можно упростить. я ж не настаиваю.

Comment: Ваше решение можно починить только для случая, если во входной последовательности нет чисел с разрядностью более одного. Потому что вы рассматриваете конкретные символы, а не токены.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var s = "0(2),1,2(3),3(2),12(10)"
console.log(s.replace(/\b(\d+)\((\d+)\)/g, (m,x,n) => Array(+n).fill(x)))
```

Comment: replace можно считать строковой функцией или нет?

Comment: @loreley а как вы думаете, если она вызывается у строки?

Comment: @teran просто одним из условий задачи является то, что нужно её решить без использования строковых функций

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется, что здесь зря используется обращение по индексу назад (строка 9 в коде), ведь мы не знаем, какой длины число было до;
лучше, если нельзя использовать встроенный метод split(","), либо написать свой, либо идти по строке и, пока не встретим запятую или "(", собирать текущее число. если первый встреченный символ был "," - просто добавляем число в вывод и идем дальше, если "(" - считываем число повторений (до символа ")") и столько раз добавляем текущее число к result (не забывая запятые, если число не последнее)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function solve(s) {
  var res = [], cur = { val: 0, count: 1 }, type = 'val';
  
  for (var c of s + ",") {
    switch (c) {
      case ",":
        for (var q=0; q<cur.count; ++q) res.push(cur.val);
        type = 'val';
        cur.val = 0;
        cur.count = 1;
        break;
      case "(":
        type = 'count';
        cur.count = 0;
        break;
      case ")":
        break;
      default: // digit
        cur[type] *= 10;
        cur[type] += +c;
    }
  }
  
  return res.join(",");
}

console.log(solve("0(2),1,2(3),3(2),12(10)"));
```